# How to get rid of horizontal margin from dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

Now the dialog looks like this:

[image]

But what I want is this:

[image: what I want is this]

Which means the dialog has to be `match_parent` in horizontal. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: pass this theme R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar to dialog constructor..

Comment: dear what you use show dialog.measns do you use AlertDIalog to show dialog

Answer (score 0):

you cen use this code

```
           dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog2);
       getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 240dp);
```

and you can make a custom style like:

```
<style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
...
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">97%</item>
<item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">97%</item>
```

enjoy your code:)